# Is this sufficient to prove that order of intervals does not matter for integrals?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that if $f$ is an integrable function at all intervals involving $a,b,$ and $c$, then no matter the order, the following holds true:

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx + \int_{b}^{c}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx$

I want to start my proof with the fact that we can use this proposition where if $a > b$, then we can say that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = -\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$. Then, can I say WLOG, this is true for $b,c$ as well as $a,c$ and end my proof there or is there an important step that I am missing that I think I indeed am?

Comment: Why "if $a > b$"?  The "negate and reverse the interval" identity is also true for $a \leq b$, so it is true for any $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Weirdly, that's what it says in the textbook.. But does my proof work for the rest of it?

Comment: You have three integrals.  You have described a way to, for each of the three in isolation, to acquire a negative sign and reverse the interval of integration.  How does this show the result?  At some point, you have to either convert the two integrals on the left-hand side into a single integral or to convert the single integral on the right-hand side into two integrals.  No amount of sign and interval flipping will perform either conversion.  Maybe pick a useful partition for the Riemann sums for the right-hand integral.

Comment: Can I use the Additive property in coherence to the above proposition then? Then I can actually utilize the part where a > b in order for the right-hand integral to be split into two.

Comment: But I'm stuck on the "regardless of the order" part since that's only true for the case where a < b < c.

Comment: It sounds like you need to consider each of the six orderings, one at a time.

Comment: The comment that was offered as a hint was that I am able to use the "this case can be applied to other situations" as long as it is viable so is it ok to just state one part and then say WLOG?

Comment: Apparently, there is an incomplete statement of the problem and hint in the Question.  Also, there is not a clear recitation of your intended proof in the Question.  With so much information missing, how would anyone know "is it ok to just state one part and then say WLOG"?

Comment: Well it sounds like I need to do more research.